# Get the links from a page using Headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

Is there a way I can get the links from a page using `headless chrome` with [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/)?

I tried with `Runtime.compileScript()` && `Runtime.runScript()` but these methods just execute scripts without returning a response...

```
const script = {
    expression: "document.links",
    sourceURL: "https://www.github.com",
    persistScript: true
}
const actionResponse = await Runtime.compileScript(script);
const result = await Runtime.runScript({scriptId: actionResponse.scriptId})
```